# Network requests with optional return type with generics in swift

Tags: ios, swift

When making requests to a server, sometimes data is expected as a result (e.g. GET) and sometimes not (e.g. PUT). In my case, I have a websocket connection which is, amongst other things, used to tell the server things (no data returned), but also to request data (data returned).

I have defined an enum with the different kinds of requests (events) for the server:

```swift
public enum OutgoingEvent: String, Codable {
    case user
    case identification
    // ... more events
    
    var objectType: Codable.Type? {
        switch(self) {
        case .user:
            User.self
        // ... more cases
        default:
            nil
        }
    }
}
```

The `objectType` is what type of object is to be expected as a result of the request (used to decode the JSON received). For some events, this is some Decodable, for others nil (no data expected as return).

**How do I write a function that I can call for all kinds of events, and get as a return either the kind of object specified by `objectType`, or nothing at all (depending on the event)?** Additionally, I need to convert from callback based function call to async/await syntax, because of the socketIO library (but this in itself works appart from the generics part).

I have tried this:

```swift
func sendWithAck<T: Codable>(event: OutgoingEvent, data: [[String : Any]], completion: @escaping (Result<T?, Error>) -> ()) throws {
            // getting data from socket ...
            guard let resultType = event.objectType else {
                completion(.success(nil))
                return
            }
            
            guard let decodedObject = try? self.decodeFromDict(object: result, type: resultType) as? T else {
                completion(.failure(ServerCommunicationError.invalidDataFromServer("Could not decode result data.")))
                return
            }
            
            completion(.success(decodedObject))
}

func sendWithAck<T: Codable>(event: OutgoingEvent, data: [[String : Any]]) async throws -> T? {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            do {
                try sendWithAck(event: event, data: data) { (result: Result<T?, ServerCommunicationError>) in
                    continuation.resume(with: result)
                }
            } catch(let error) {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
```

But when calling like:

```swift
let User : User = try await ServerService.shared.sendWithAck(event: event, data: [updateData])
```

I get *"Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"* and *"Cannot convert value of type 'T?' to specified type 'User'"*

Comment: The returned type is not `T` it is `T?`. Just change `let User: User` to `let User: User?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an enum, you can use a `protocol`, with each enum case being a different type conforming to that protocol. Then you can add the output type as an associated type.

```
protocol OutgoingEvent {
    associatedtype Output: Codable
    
    // other propertie can go here too...
}

struct UserEvent: OutgoingEvent {
    typealias Output = User
    
    // implement the other properties (if any) here
}

struct SomeOtherEvent: OutgoingEvent {
    typealias Output = Never
}

// these extensions allow you to use the same syntax as enum cases, 
// ".user", ".someOther" etc.
extension OutgoingEvent where Self == UserEvent {
    static var user: UserEvent { UserEvent() }
}

extension OutgoingEvent where Self == SomeOtherEvent {
    static var someOther: SomeOtherEvent { SomeOtherEvent() }
}
```

Normally `Void` would be used to mean "no output", but `Void` is not `Codable`, so I've used `Never` instead. You can also create your own `Void`-like type (a type that only has one valid value):

```
enum Unit {
    case unit
}
```

Then `sendWithAck` can be rewritten with a `<Event: OutgoingEvent>` type parameter instead. `T` in your code is now `Event.Output`:

```
func sendWithAck<Event: OutgoingEvent>(event: Event, data: [[String : Any]], completion: @escaping (Result<Event.Output?, Error>) -> ()) throws {
    guard Event.Output.self != Never.self else {
        completion(.success(nil))
        return
    }
    
    guard let decodedObject = try? self.decodeFromDict(object: result, type: Event.Output.self) as? Event.Output else {
        completion(.failure(ServerCommunicationError.invalidDataFromServer("Could not decode result data.")))
        return
    }
    
    completion(.success(decodedObject))
}
```

If you use your own `Unit` type, the closure can just take a `Result<Event.Output, Error>` (no optionals), because you can just pass `Unit.unit` to the completion handler.

```
func sendWithAck<Event: OutgoingEvent>(event: Event, data: [[String : Any]], completion: @escaping (Result<Event.Output, Error>) -> ()) throws {
    guard Event.Output.self != Unit.self else {
        completion(.success(Unit.unit as! Event.Output))
        return
    }
```

Usage:

```
try sendWithAck(event: .user, data: []) { result in
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you omit the decoding when you expect `nil` you change the semantic. IMHO,  it's required to decode the result in any case. If you don't you won't catch protocol errors.

Comment: This allows the return type to be determined automatically by the event that is given as a parameter, which is even better! But couldn't one use the protocol on the enum itself somehow? These extensions seem somewhat like a workaround, making the answer by @Joakim much simpler..

Comment: @CouchDeveloper What semantics have I changed? OP's code doesn't decode the result if there is no output type either. Presumably protocol errors are handled in the `// getting data from socket ...` part which has been omitted.

Comment: @ambassador It's not really a workaround. This is a pattern that SwiftUI really likes to use. See [`PrimitiveButtonStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/primitivebuttonstyle) for an example of such an "enum-like" protocol.

Comment: Yes, the OP didn't handle this case, too. The probably correct way is to be defensive, i.e. when `nil` is expected and the socket returns no data, we should replace the data with JSON "null", so that decoding is still in effect and actually returns `nil` instead of a decoder error.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yeah, I agree with that. The question isn't really about this, so I didn't address it.

Comment: @Sweeper I see, thanks! For the comments about the "decoding errors", what exactly should be changed? As you said, if the return type is nil (or Never in this case) the decoding will never run, so why could there be any errors?

Comment: Could you also elaborate on how I can use the enum syntax `.user` and so on? Let's say I had a function `func foo(event: IncomingEvent)`, where before I could use `switch event { case .room` How can this be achieved with this protocol?

Comment: @ambassador You can just check the metatype of the type parameter. `if Event.self == RoomEvent.self { ... }`. If you want to use a switch for that, you can add an actual enum - the protocol would require implementations to return a case from this enum. That said, it might be better to just *not* do this. Add a protocol requirement for whatever the switch is doing, and dynamically dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the expected return type as parameter to the function

```
func sendWithAck<T: Codable>(_: T.Type = T.self, event: OutgoingEvent, data: [[String : Any]]) async throws -> T?
```

and the default value means you can use it in two ways, by passing the type

```
let user = try await sendWithAck(User.self, event: .user, data: [["Foo": "Bar"]])
```

or implicitly by defining the return type

```
let user: User? = try await sendWithAck(event: .user, data: [["Foo": "Bar"]])
```

Comment: Can I use `_ type: T.Type = Never.self` to set a default value for the events that have no return value? Or how do I call this function when the associated event it is called with does not have any type, since it expects no returned result?

Comment: You could but then you can't use the second example in my answer. Personally I would keep it as it is and pass Never.self when nothing is returned but its up to you and what suits your taste and use case best. My preferred way, `try await sendWithAck(Never.self, event: .user, data: [["name": "Bla"]])`